# After the journey is over, why did Maetel go for another journey?

Tags: galaxy-express-999

In final episode of Galaxy express 999 (episode 113), after Tetsuro & Maetel destroy planet Peuromesyum, Maetel left Tetsuro behind just to guide another boy to the future (or something). But the whole reason she had to travel was, just so she can 'provide' that boy to her mother. So I'm wondering after this thing is over, why does she still need to travel? Can't she just wind up with Tetsuro?

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I think it's answered in the episode. The narrator at the end says that 999 is a train that travels in the heart of every boy, maybe Testuro had been travelling alone all this time, and Maetel was just a vision he was keeping in his mind and she exists in every boy.